# MediaWiki not returning continue parameter

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions

I'm using this API request:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=10000&gscoord=51.540951897949|-0.051086739997922&format=json&gslimit=50&continue=

which delivers `50` results. I want to use the 'continue' parameter to get the next page of results. According to the documentation I should get a `continue` field back in the results. I don't get any such result so can't get the next page.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: It seems to me that `list=geosearch` does not support `continue`. So, `gslimit=500` gives you all the results you will be able to get. It might be worth to [report this issue](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dave, as @svick says, it seems `list=geosearch` (which is part of [extension:GeoData](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:GeoData#API)) does not support continuation; indeed, it actually returns a "batchcomplete" element to indicate no more results (see in [human-readable form](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=10000&gscoord=51.540951897949|-0.051086739997922&format=jsonfm&formatversion=2&gslimit=50&continue=)).

I think you should either just get the maximum number of results (500 for users, 5000 for bots on Wikipedia), or if that's not satisfactory for your use case (which is?), pipe in at [task T78703](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T78703).
(Or, if you believe it to be a separate issue, [report a new bug](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/maniphest/task/create/?projects=MediaWiki-extensions-GeoData).